# Select Multiple column from multiple table and every two tables have an idenetity column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a Store Procedure as like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetApplicationsByLoginName]
@loginName
AS
VARCHAR(30)
--,@IsSuperAdmin   as bit

AS
BEGIN
SELECT MA.appName,
       MA.appId,
       MA.CompatiableDeviceType,
       MA.appShortCode,
       MA.downloadAppUrl,
       MA.CurrentVersion,
       MAI.AppIconUrl,
       MAI.SplashLogoUrl,
       MAI.HeaderLogoUrl,
       MM.moduleName
FROM   mstApp MA
       LEFT OUTER JOIN mstAppImages MAI
            ON  MAI.appId = MA.appId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN trnAppModule TAM
            ON  TAM.appId = MA.appId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN trnAppGroups TAG
            ON  TAG.appModuleId = TAM.appModuleId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN mstModule MM
            ON  MM.moduleId = TAM.moduleId
WHERE  TAG.loginName = 'kmg'

GO
```

Please tell me how can I create a store procedure that get all these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just change this line:

```
where TAG.loginName ='kmg'
```

To:

```
where TAG.loginName = @LoginName
```

And then you would call it by using:

```
EXEC uspGetApplicationsByLoginName 'kmg'
```